Debugging Wi-Fi Not Connecting on Raspberry Pi 4 (Bullseye)
Hi I'm running the following O/S on Raspberry Pi 4:
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye

I've got a unit that can scan for Wi-Fi networks and see them, but when I put the appropriate block on my /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf file, then reboot the Raspberry Pi, it won't associate with the Wi-Fi network.
How do I get a better idea off why it's not connecting to Wi-Fi. This is seemingly not something as simple as, I'm typing in the wrong password, or there is something wrong with my router configuration, since I can get another Raspberry Pi 4 to connect without issue. Likewise, I have tried unsuccessfully to connect the non-connecting Raspberry Pi 4 to multiple different networks.
What kind of diagnostic commands can I run on the non-working Raspberry Pi 4 to narrow down what the problem is and fix it?
At this time, my solution space can't include updating to a newer version of the O/S, or in using something other than wpa_supplicant.conf to configure the connection.

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

You can run wpa_supplicant from the command line in the foreground to get a clue about the problem:
sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0

See man wpa_supplicant for more details.  There is also wpa_cli, which is interactive (hence more complicated).
You will first need to stop the wpa_supplicant service and whatever DHCP client/networking service you are using, since the latter will probably try and (re)start the former itself otherwise. On bullseye dhcpcd is the default, and it manages wpa_supplicant so:
sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd

Should do it.  Check to see if wpa_supplicant is running w/ ps -C wpa_supplicant.  If so, sudo killall wpa_supplicant and check again.  If that doesn't work, try sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd and reboot (you will have to enable it again later).
Note that wpa_supplicant won't connect you to the internet, it just associates you with the wifi network.

Thanks. What causes it to connect to an associated Wi-Fi network?

"Note that wpa_supplicant won't connect you to the internet, it just associates you with the wifi network."  There's a difference between those two things, if that was not clear.  You first need to be connected to the link layer (wpa_supplicant does this for wifi), then you can be connected to the internet layer (usually via a DHCP client such as dhcpcd). The latter uses IP addresses, hence you can be associated with a wifi network even though you do not have an IP address.

Ok, sure, I understand that... How does one determine whether or not the pi is associated vs that it isn't installing an IP address?

Did you try and use wpa_supplicant as described above?  It produces detailed, reasonably clear output including words such as "associated", etc -- at the very least, you will get an error log you can cut n' paste online.  WRT the IP address, that can be negotiated afterward with dhcpcd or, more simply, dhclient -v wlan0 (but you may have to install dhclient, which of course requires internet access...
